# access list element from thread

Tags: c#, wpf, list, multithreading

I have a "List" in the main application and I am trying to access its elements from within a thread. I am getting this exception:
{"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}    System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DispatcherOperation d = myListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => 
{ 
    // access your listbox and return something
}));
```

Then demand your DispatcherOperation for the return value

```
myValue = d.Result; //Result is of type Object
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My list is a List<Bitmap Image> and the application freezes when I am trying to get the n-th element using your method.

Comment: In that case, copy the UI dispatcher like this. Dispatcher UIdispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; before you start your thread. Now in your thread instead of myListBox.Dispatcher use UIdispatcher.Invoke(...)    
Can you tell me how u called the Invoke method. I mean your code.

Comment: Use Invoke and not BeginInvoke. cast the d.Result into the desired type

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross thread by declaring a delegate.

```
private delegate void thread_delegate();
```

then create a method and put all your methods that access your list.

```
private void SampleMethod()
{
....
}
```

then create a method for your thread.
Inside that method invoke your method whick

```
private void ThreadMethod()
{

           thread_delegate d = new thread_delegate(SampleMethod);
            d.Invoke();
}
```

On your statement where you create your thread...

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));    
 t.Start();
```

Comment: I already tried this approach, and it doesn't work. I get the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the UI from a non-UI thread.

Read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2927256/Re-WPF-Delegates-The-calling-thread-cannot-access-.aspx

and this: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

Comment: Thanks, but I am able to set a value to a list member. I don't know how to retrieve a value of it using the dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
MylistBox is a ListBox

```
namespace TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread th = new Thread(AccessList);
            th.Start(MylistBox);
        }

        void AccessList(Object O)
        {
            ListBox lBox = O as ListBox;
            for (int i = 0; i < lBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(lBox.Items[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```